# Firefox touch scrolling not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, mobile

I have an issue with Firefox. In both responsive mode and Firefox Mobile to be accurate.
The touch scrolling isn't working on my website. (But the scroll with the mouse is working on Responsive mode)

It works fine on Chrome mobile & Safari mobile.

I checked online and I already tried the `dom.w3c_touch_events.enabled` set to 1. It was actually set to 1 by default.
I think it's an issue on the JS/CSS side but I can't see where.

I use SASS and Pleeease to compile it and it's a React app compiled with webpack.
Also I use the method `fetch` to call my webservices if it can have any influence but I doubt it. (and have a polyfill for it)

I tried to nuke totally my CSS and it still didn't work.

Happy to share URL if people want to see the actual problem. I just don't want to be seen as a spam. Also I will share a test server and not the live one. (problem is the same anyway)

Comment: Firefox seem to have some issues with touch scrolling, which might have been fixed on latest versions of firefox, see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=736048 and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=978679, but there could still be outstanding issues. The last fix was on 2015 dec. Outstanding see: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=888305

Comment: The version of firefox required for touch to work would be 43 or later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the (stupid) solution and posting it as it might be helpful to someone.

I had a `overflow:hidden;` added by mistake in `html, body {` into my SASS.
For some reason the responsive mode in Firefox is still not working (bug? cache? I don't know...). But once I tried again on my Firefox mobile it was gone.

Looks like Chrome and Safari are ignoring this CSS but not Firefox.

For the record I am on last versions on all my browsers.